# Accessing Network Drive from behind Sub-network Router

Tags: networking, router, drive

I am connecting the router to a corporate network. Then I have 3 computers connecting to this router (local IP 192.168.1.2-4).
Assuming I want to access a network drive named "ADrive" (on the same corporate LAN) from any of those 3 PCs, how do I do it? ("\\ADrive" does not work, neither does replacing the network drive with its IP, cannot ping either - it's like I'm on a totally separate network).

Answer (score 0):

getting ping to work is the first step.

you have a segment connected to 3 computers. you also need to have an interface connected to the corporate lan. in addition, the router that you have connected needs to know where to send packets that are not local.  setup a default route to the default gateway on the corporate lan.  that will get packets to travel to the corporate lan.  to get packets to come back, the router on the corporate lan will need to know how to route packets back to your router.  you will to add a route to corporate lan router advertising your 192.168.1.x network (assuming that network doesn't exist somewhere on the network already).

Comment: "setup a default route to the default gateway on the corporate lan" -> how do I do this? do you mean port forwarding? I don't know what ports UNC uses.
"the router on the corporate lan will need to know how to route packets back to your router" -> do you mean route back to the computers? because there is only 1 router here that is mine, and it is plugged directly to the wall ethernet connection of the corporate network.

Comment: my best advice would be to get someone from the corporate lan group to assist you.